# Conflicting declaration for static variable with template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, gcc, clang

I try to define a static variable outside the class scope like:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
  void set(int i)  {
  }
  static constexpr decltype(&Foo<T>::set) i = &Foo<T>::set;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr decltype(&Foo<T>::set) Foo<T>::i;
```

[Live example.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(colouriseAsm:'0',compileOnChange:'0'),source:'template%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Astruct+Foo+%7B%0A++void+set(int+i)++%7B%0A++%7D%0A++static+constexpr+decltype(%26Foo%3CT%3E::set)+i+%3D+%26Foo%3CT%3E::set%3B%0A%7D%3B%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aconstexpr+decltype(%26Foo%3CT%3E::set)+Foo%3CT%3E::i%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++Foo%3Cint%3E+f%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:37.17412935323384,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g540,filters:(b:'0',binary:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+5.4',t:'0')),k:29.492537313432837,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+5.4',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

But I get following error (for all gcc  >= 4.7):

```
conflicting declaration 'constexpr decltype (& Foo<T>::set(int))   Foo<T>::i'
note: previous declaration as 'constexpr decltype (& Foo<T>::set(int)) Foo<T>::i'
```

All clang version (clang >= 3.2) do not have any problem with my code.

The problem seems to be the function reference. It works without using a template class.

My questions:

- Is it a bug?
- How to do it in gcc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's a bug or not, but you can do it like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
  void set(int i)  {
  }

  typedef decltype(&Foo<T>::set) function_type;
  static constexpr function_type i = &Foo<T>::set;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr typename Foo<T>::function_type Foo<T>::i;

int main()
{
  Foo<int> f;
}
```